# Do my web pages need to be in HTML5 to use the Data Highlighter or Schema.org Microdata?

Tags: html, schema.org, google-search-console, microdata

Do my web pages need to be written in HTML5 to use the Data Highlighter?  Do my web pages need to be written in HTML5 to use the Schema.org Microdata?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the Data Highlighter, but yes, in order to use Microdata (whether with schema.org or any other vocabulary) you need to use HTML5. Microdata was originally part of HTML5 (it was removed from the spec some time ago, and now exists separately, but is still only valid in HTML5).

However you can still use schema.org in non-HTML5 web pages by embedding it using RDFa or JSON-LD instead of Microdata. And obviously you can also use RDFa and JSON-LD in HTML5 web pages as well.