# Do web pages need to be in HTML5 to use the Data Highlighter or Schema Microdata?

Tags: google-search-console, microdata

Do my web pages need to be in HTML5 to use the Data Highlighter or Schema.org Microdata?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do my web pages need to be in HTML5 to use the Data Highlighter or Schema.org Microdata?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572742/do-my-web-pages-need-to-be-in-html5-to-use-the-data-highlighter-or-schema-org-mi)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implement Microdata to a non HTML5 page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651749/implement-microdata-to-a-non-html5-page)

Comment: See this answer -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651749/implement-microdata-to-a-non-html5-page

Answer (score 0):

No, you can use whatever HTML version you want, just make sure it's at least fairly valid.

You can test what Google sees from your structured data with [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/)

Comment: do you have a reference for that?